# Be able to scroll within underlying element while cursor is over position absolute element in front of it

Tags: javascript, css, z-index, absolute

How can I be able to scroll `article` while having my mouse cursor over `.header` while still having `.header` clickable? If I set `z-index: -1` to `.header` I'm able to scroll while having the cursor over `.header`, but it's no longer clickable.

**[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/CK7z8/show/)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CK7z8/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="off-canvas-wrap">
      <div class="inner-wrap">
          <div class="header">
              I should be clickable
          </div>

          <article class="small-12 columns">
              <div style="height:5000px">
              </div>
          </article>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
article {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
article,
body,
html,
.off-canvas-wrap, 
.off-canvas-wrap .inner-wrap,
.row {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #000;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Not possible, as far as I know, because this is how mouse/scroll events are handled. However, there might be a JS-based solution I can think of, albeit being quite convoluted and complicated.

Comment: Listen to `mousewheel` and scroll `article` in an eventhandler function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a CSS solution, there is none — this is because of how mouse events are directly related to the visibility of the item to the pointer/cursor: e.g. if you place `.header` in the back such that it is not accessible (so that scroll events on `article` can be triggered), it will not register a click event, too.

A JS-based solution would be listening to the `mousewheel()` event (with [this plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel), available as a [CDN-hosted plugin](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-mousewheel/), too) and then manually triggering scrolling on the `article` element. However, this does not replicate the default scrolling behavior on individual OSes, and may appear choppy on OSes that has smoothed scrolling events (like OS X).

Without further ado:

```
// Cache article's position from top (might change if the page is loaded with a hash, so we cannot declare it as 0)
var fromTop = $('article').scrollTop();

$('.header').mousewheel(function(e,d) {
    // Prevent default scrolling behavior, even when .header is overflowing
    e.preventDefault();

    // Trigger scroll in window
    // You can change how much to amplify the 'd', which is the delta (distance registered from the scrollwheel). I have chosen it to multiply it by 10
    fromTop = fromTop - d*10;
    $(this).next('article').scrollTop(fromTop);
}).click(function() {
    // Just testing
    alert('Header is clicked on!');
});
```

Here is the proof-of-concept JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/CK7z8/2/

**Warning:** In the event that there are multiple `.header` elements targeting multiple `article` elements on the same page, you will have to iterate through each `.header`-`article` pair and cache the `fromTop` separately for each pair.